# Crash when I open the same Gluon App twice in Android

Tags: android, javafxports, gluon

1) Reproduce:

- configure the example gluon app to react on Intents (e.g. Image sharing)
- now open the app, one time over intent (e.g. sharing in a messenger), and the other time normally
- as soon as you touch the screen of any of the two running apps
- CRASH

2) Error:

```
04-05 13:43:33.376: E/AndroidRuntime(5970): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke com.sun.glass.ui.android.DalvikInput.onMultiTouchEvent method by reflection
```

3) Reason (my guess)

- The backend receives a touch event and tries to froward it to the correct application
- The application exists multiple times
- can't decide on the correct one (the open r the closed one)

4) What should normally happen

- only forward the event to the currently open/active app

Where do I post this bug?
Is this a pure javaFXports bug? (if so, where EXACTLY do I post it there)

EDIT:
To reproduce even a basic Hello World Gluon is enaugh.
You just have to enable the app being called with intents:
I did it like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Could you share the minimum code that reproduces the issue (via gist/pastebin). We'll open an issue with this. Anyway you can create the issue yourself [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues?status=new&status=open)

Comment: I edited my Question. You dont need code to reproduce it you just need a basic Gluon App and enable intents.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce it now, and I get the same error. We'll file an issue

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues/67/crash-when-i-open-the-same-app-twice-in I already posted it here, I hope I did it right

Comment: Yes, but you can attach the stacktrace to your issue.

Comment: I'll do that, thank you (might take a few hours)